# How can I compile cuda code (nvcc) using Bazel

Tags: c++, cuda, bazel

I would like to compile a simple cu file using bazel.
I've created a/third_party folder which looks like this:

```
opencv.bzl
opencv.BUILD
qt.bzl
qt.BUILD
...
...
...
```

for qt I've created a macro `qt_cc_library` in `qt.bzl` to handle qt files, and I would like to add a similar library/binary for cuda

I don't understand what I should add to the `WORKSPACE`/`cuda.bzl`/`cuda.BUILD` files, and all the online references are old and broken (e.g. [this](https://github.com/llvim/bazel_rule_cuda),[this](https://github.com/Hibbert-pku/bazel_nvcc)).
I've look at the [extension page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/concepts.html) but when trying to compile I get errors and cannot debug the bzl file.

This should be pretty basic but for there is no working example for compiling cuda (`nvcc`) Code with bazel.

Comment: Given that there is no built-in CUDA support in Bazel [yet](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6578), and you say "but when trying to compile I get errors and cannot debug the bzl file", it would probably be better to describe your problem more thoroughly in your question. Someone  might be able to suggest a fix based on what you have done

Comment: Before posting this bounty I've tried several different approaches, some are posted in the above question. Instead of posting fixes, I seek for a compact solution: compile an empty kernel code using Cuda by defining the Bazel target and workspace, creating a binary file using nvcc. If there's anything I can add to make it more specific, please comment on this question

Comment: "If there's anything I can add to make it more specific, please comment on this question" -- I though I just did that. You said your attempt to compile produces errors -- what errors?

Comment: well, https://github.com/llvim/bazel_rule_cuda is 3 years old. following the usage fails as it needs some tweaking (I guess syntax has chaged as the WORKSPACE file doesnt compile - load and cuda_configure syntax is worng). But after passing this step, even then I get that it tries to run gcc instead of nvcc ("...error executing command /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc ..." is there's a flag/en. variable I need to set?

Answer (score 1):

I would try [rules_cuda](https://github.com/bazel-contrib/rules_cuda).

From the README:

> These rules provide some macros and rules that make it easier to build CUDA with Bazel.